# Plotting frequency of occurrences based on start/end times in R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, plot

I have a "trips" dataset that includes a unique trip id, and a start and end time (the specific hour and minute) of the trips. These trips were all taken on the same day. I am trying to determine the number of cars on the road at any given time and plot it as a line graph using ggplot in R. In other words, a car is "on the road" at any time in between its start and end time.

The most similar example I can find uses the following structure:

```
yearly_counts <- trips %>%
                 count(year, trip_id)

ggplot(data = yearly_counts, mapping = aes(x = year, y = n)) +
     geom_line()
```

Would the best approach be to modify this structure have an "minutesByHour_count" variable that has a count for every minute of every hour? This seems inefficient to me, and still doesn't solve the problem of getting the counts from the start/end time.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Please try to add a working example (including data, possibly mock data) – it greatly enhances your chance of getting a useful reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on counting each start as an additional car, and each end as a reduction in the count:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  gather(type, time, c(start_hour, end_hour)) %>%
  mutate(count_chg = if_else(type == "start_hour", 1, -1)) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(car_count = cumsum(count_chg)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, car_count)) +
  geom_step()
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  uniqueID = 1:60,
  start_hour = seq(8, 12, length.out = 60),
  dur_hour = 0.05*1:60
)
df$end_hour = df$start_hour + df$dur_hour
df$dur_hour = NULL
```