# Counting obeservation by minute

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to count how many cars are on the road during each minute of the day. My date range is an entire month, and my data includes start time and end time of each car.

I am going to graph which periods of the day have the most traffic, i.e. at 09:42 there are 19 cars on the road vs. at 11:21 there are 11 cars on the road.

There might be a way to do this with `dplyr`, but I am not familiar with that package. This program is currently run in [sas](/questions/tagged/sas) but needs to be re-written in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

My current workaround uses a series of nested `for` loops. The only issue is that these loops take nearly an hour to compute since there is upwards of 86,000 rows of data.

I have `POSIX` variables with start and end times as below:

```
    StartTime           EndTime             TypeOfCar
1   2019-07-01 12:00:00 2019-07-01 18:14:00 32S
2   2019-07-01 15:00:00 2019-07-01 20:47:00 32S
3   2019-07-01 16:29:00 2019-07-01 22:24:00 32S
4   2019-07-01 18:00:00 2019-07-01 23:46:00 32S
5   2019-07-01 13:12:00 2019-07-01 14:57:00 32S
6   2019-07-02 04:30:00 2019-07-02 10:05:00 32S
7   2019-07-01 20:10:00 2019-07-01 22:32:00 737
8   2019-07-02 06:40:00 2019-07-02 12:05:00 32S
9   2019-07-02 02:10:00 2019-07-02 07:43:00 32S
```

I am looking for an output similar to:

```
12:01AM - 5 cars
12:02AM - 5 cars
12:03AM - 4 cars
...
...
...
09:42AM - 16 cars
...
11:48AM - 21 cars
...
...
5:12PM - 32 cars
...
10:59PM - 0 cars
11:00PM - 0 cars
```

An important note is that I want the times of day without any traffic also. In total, I want to see counts for all 1440 minutes in the day. The goal is to generate a graph similar to the following:

[image: graph example]

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033871/6851825  This approach will be *dramatically* faster, I expect <1 second: gather your starts and ends into long form and count each as a +1 or a -1, then take the cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  transmute(intervals = list(seq.POSIXt(floor_date(StartTime, unit = "min"), 
                                        ceiling_date(EndTime, unit = "min"), 
                                        by = "min"))) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  group_by(intervals) %>% 
  count
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 1,303 x 2
#> # Groups:   intervals [1,303]
#>    intervals               n
#>    <dttm>              <int>
#>  1 2019-07-01 12:00:00     1
#>  2 2019-07-01 12:01:00     1
#>  3 2019-07-01 12:02:00     1
#>  4 2019-07-01 12:03:00     1
#>  5 2019-07-01 12:04:00     1
#>  6 2019-07-01 12:05:00     1
#>  7 2019-07-01 12:06:00     1
#>  8 2019-07-01 12:07:00     1
#>  9 2019-07-01 12:08:00     1
#> 10 2019-07-01 12:09:00     1
#> # ... with 1,293 more rows
```

***Data:***

```r
read.table(text="    StartTime           EndTime             TypeOfCar
                  1   2019-07-01_12:00:00 2019-07-01_18:14:00 32S
                  2   2019-07-01_15:00:00 2019-07-01_20:47:00 32S
                  3   2019-07-01_16:29:00 2019-07-01_22:24:00 32S
                  4   2019-07-01_18:00:00 2019-07-01_23:46:00 32S
                  5   2019-07-01_13:12:00 2019-07-01_14:57:00 32S
                  6   2019-07-02_04:30:00 2019-07-02_10:05:00 32S
                  7   2019-07-01_20:10:00 2019-07-01_22:32:00 737
                  8   2019-07-02_06:40:00 2019-07-02_12:05:00 32S
                  9   2019-07-02_02:10:00 2019-07-02_07:43:00 32S", 
                       header=T,
                       stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1


df1$StartTime <- as.POSIXct(df1$StartTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", tz="EST")
df1$EndTime <- as.POSIXct(df1$EndTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", tz="EST")
```

Answer (score -1):

We can create a sequence of 1 minute duration between each `StartTime` and `EndTime` and `count` the occurrence of each minute.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unnest(time = purrr::map2(StartTime, EndTime, seq, by = "1 min")) %>%
  select(-StartTime, -EndTime) %>%
  count(time) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 1,303 x 2
#   time                    n
#   <dttm>              <int>
# 1 2019-07-01 18:00:00     4
# 2 2019-07-01 18:01:00     4
# 3 2019-07-01 18:02:00     4
# 4 2019-07-01 18:03:00     4
# 5 2019-07-01 18:04:00     4
# 6 2019-07-01 18:05:00     4
# 7 2019-07-01 18:06:00     4
# 8 2019-07-01 18:07:00     4
# 9 2019-07-01 18:08:00     4
#10 2019-07-01 18:09:00     4
# … with 1,293 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(StartTime = structure(c(1561982400, 1561993200, 
1561998540, 1562004000, 1561986720, 1562041800, 1562011800, 1562049600, 
1562033400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
EndTime = structure(c(1562004840, 1562014020, 1562019840, 
1562024760, 1561993020, 1562061900, 1562020320, 1562069100, 
1562053380), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
TypeOfCar = c("32S", "32S", "32S", "32S", "32S", "32S", "737", 
"32S", "32S")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9"), class = "data.frame")
```